# Codepush App not installed - Messege When Trying to Install after distributing?

Tags: code-push, react-native-code-push

[image]

I Am really getting confused , it is APK Signing issue.

> i created a new react native project ,
>    uploaded it on github.
>   then build it in app center.
>   and downloaded it. 
>   but when i am trying to install it.
>   it shows APP NOT INSTALLED ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

Build on your machine and upload the release to your device locally. This is usually a configuration problem that will appear whether you are using App Center or not. Should be easy to spot.